# How to drop a row of a tensor tensor containing nan in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor:

```
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan],
                                       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]))
```

and would like to drop the row that has nan. For instance:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])>
```

How do you do this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer only works in `eager mode`. For all situations, one can try,

```
tf.boolean_mask(tensor, tf.reduce_all(~tf.math.is_nan(tensor), axis=-1))
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will remove nan rows:

```
tensor[~np.isnan(tensor).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: That seems like a very bad way to do it...
Maybe with some indexing to not miss any rows?

Comment: @mCalado I have changed my answer again. Please take a look at it